# Lipschitz convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to think of a differentiable Lipschitz convex function of $2$ variables other than the linear function, but I am unable to think of one. Can I have some examples, please?

Comment: Do you mean Lipschitz and convex? Check $(x,y)\mapsto |x-y|$

Answer (score 0):

What about 
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{ \|x\|^2 + \epsilon}
$$?

Answer (score 0):

Think about any differentiable function whose derivative is bounded

Like  $\sin(x + y)$  or $\cos (x + y)$